# Reverse Calculating RPM from Speed, Gear Ratio, Diff Ratio and Radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wish to calculate what revolutions per minute an engine would be going when changing from gear 1 to gear 2.

I am currently calculating the speed with this equation:

```
(60/63360) * ((rpm * (pi * 2) * radius) / (gear ratio * differential ratio)
```

Where Radius = 12, gear ratio = 2.774 and diff ratio = 3.1; for the rpm at 8500, the speed is 47.

When changing from gear 1 (2.774) to gear 2 (1.974), how do I calculate the theoretical RPM of the engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text {rpm} = \frac {63360}{60} *\frac {\text{gear ratio * differential ratio * speed}} {2\pi \text{ * radius}}$$